# Is there a way to collect the RSC characteristic from the Zwift foot pod

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to collect Running Speed and Cadence (RSC from a Zwift food pod. I have identified the  RSC measurement characteristic 2A53 but there is an additional characteristic listed FF00 which I am not familiar with (see Light Blue images) . I suspect that the foot pod can be used only with the proprietary application. Is there a way to collect the RSC characteristic from this foot pod?[image: Light Blue App output when connected to Zwift foot pod]

Comment: 2A53 is not a "read" characteristic, it's a notification.  Can you read from 2A54 or 2A5D?

Comment: yes, I can retrieve data when i ask LightBlue to read from 2A54 or 2A5D but no notifications are coming through for 2A53 which would contain the running cadence info that I want.